# Symfony2 overriding bundle HTML form input constraints

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to override FOSUserBundle's max username length. Seems simple enough but I can't manage to do it.

validation.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        username:
            - Length: { max: 5, groups: [CustomRegistration] }
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    [...]
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            validation_groups: [CustomRegistration]
```

Validation itself works fine. If user provides username longer than 5 characters Symfony shows an error that it should not be longer than 5 characters. The problem is that the HTML form input still uses default FOSUserBundle value (255). Form builder seems to totally ignore validation groups. Is there any way I can tell form builder to use my constraints?

I want to mention that HTML validation works when I use XML format but I need to use YAML and it works only by coincidence so I would not like to rely on such quirk.

I also tried to provide custom type in hope that it will change anything but it didn't. Username input still uses maxlength value of 255. For reference:

getDefaultOptions @ AppBundle/Form/RegistrationFormType.php

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return [
        'data_class'        => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'CustomRegistration']
    ];
}
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    [...]
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: appbundle_registration
```

services.yml

```
services:
    appbundle.registration.form.type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: appbundle_registration }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add max-length HTML attribute manually to the field.
Validation has no effect on HTML attributes.

buildForm @ AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType

```
$builder->add("username", "text", array("attr" => array("maxlength" => "5")));
```

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#max-length

If it doesnt solve the issue, take a look at your template. It can be setted there too..

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. It is not true that validation has no effect on HTML attributes. If specific HTML attributes are not provided Symfony2 tries to guess them based on the validation constraints. I just thought that I was doing something wrong. This behavior is not documented though. I thought about adding fields from a controller or even in a template but I hoped I could resolve this problem in a more civilized manner. I will use your solution since it's the best workaround I can think of.

Comment: Can you show me where HTML attributes guessed by Symfony? I've never seen that before, and i'm really curious.

Comment: You're right, I've done a little reseach. It's done by ValidatorTypeGuesser.
[link](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Validator/ValidatorTypeGuesser.php).
Sorry I don't rely on form guessers.
Then maybe you sould clear cache to apply changes on your validation config?

Comment: I cleared cache multiple times. It just doesn't seem to take validation groups under consideration and handles constraints in order of parsing. I hoped I did some rookie mistake or should have done it slightly differently. It just seems so natural to have consistent PHP and HTML validation and to not repeat constraints in config and template/form file that I can't believe it isn't (officially and fully) a thing.

Comment: I digged deeper in maxlength guessing, and as you see validation groups has not taken in consideration in guessing, first "Length" constraint will be used. And as I see it is not possible to prioritize custom constraint against the FOSUser's constraints.

Comment: That's what I thought. It's a shame. It would have been a nifty feature. Thanks for your dedication.